# Iterate over JSON arrays with javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having problems with extracting two arrays from json using javascript and outputting them to a bootstrap list.

In testing this I've been able to get this far. I can't quite figure what's wrong.

```js
var data = [{
  "title": "Ligo First Light",
  "date": "2012-06-23",
  "category": "scheduled",
  "wikipedia": "The first direct observation of gravitational waves was made on 14 September 2015 and was announced by the LIGO and Virgo collaborations on 11 February 2016.[3][4][5] Previously, gravitational waves had only been inferred indirectly, via their effect on the timing of pulsars in binary star systems. The waveform, detected by both LIGO observatories,[6] matched the predictions of general relativity[7][8][9] for a gravitational wave emanating from the inward spiral and merger of a pair of black holes of around 36 and 29 solar masses and the subsequent ringdown of the single resulting black hole.[note 2] The signal was named GW150914 (from Gravitational Wave and the date of observation 2015-09-14).[3][11] It was also the first observation of a binary black hole merger, demonstrating both the existence of binary stellar-mass black hole systems and the fact that such mergers could occur within the current age of the universe.",
  "youtube": [{
      "publishDate": "1976-03-04T04:19:34.259Z",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/B4XzLDM3Py8"
    },
    {
      "publishDate": "1976-03-04T04:19:34.259Z",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/CKynfOx3-ac"
    }
  ],
  "articles": [{
      "title": "Observation of Gravitational Waves from a Binary Black Hole Merger",
      "publishDate": "1976-03-04T04:19:34.259Z",
      "url": "https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102"
    },
    {
      "title": "First observation of gravitational waves",
      "publishDate": "1997-11-03T10:03:39.123Z",
      "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves"
    },
    {
      "title": "Gravitational Waves Detected 100 Years After Einstein's Prediction",
      "publishDate": "1997-11-03T10:03:39.123Z",
      "url": "https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20160211"
    }
  ]
}];


function getArrayByName(name) {
  return data.filter(
    function(data) {
      return data.name == name
    }
  );
}

var found = getArrayByName('youtube');

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = found[0].url;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: There is nothing with `name` of `"youtube"`?

Comment: There isn't an object in your array with the property of `name` either, can you please add your expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
var data = [{
  "title": "Ligo First Light",
  "date": "2012-06-23",
  "category": "scheduled",
  "wikipedia": "The first direct observation of gravitational waves was made on 14 September 2015 and was announced by the LIGO and Virgo collaborations on 11 February 2016.[3][4][5] Previously, gravitational waves had only been inferred indirectly, via their effect on the timing of pulsars in binary star systems. The waveform, detected by both LIGO observatories,[6] matched the predictions of general relativity[7][8][9] for a gravitational wave emanating from the inward spiral and merger of a pair of black holes of around 36 and 29 solar masses and the subsequent ringdown of the single resulting black hole.[note 2] The signal was named GW150914 (from Gravitational Wave and the date of observation 2015-09-14).[3][11] It was also the first observation of a binary black hole merger, demonstrating both the existence of binary stellar-mass black hole systems and the fact that such mergers could occur within the current age of the universe.",
  "youtube": [{
      "publishDate": "1976-03-04T04:19:34.259Z",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/B4XzLDM3Py8"
    },
    {
      "publishDate": "1976-03-04T04:19:34.259Z",
      "url": "https://www.youtube.com/embed/CKynfOx3-ac"
    }
  ],
  "articles": [{
      "title": "Observation of Gravitational Waves from a Binary Black Hole Merger",
      "publishDate": "1976-03-04T04:19:34.259Z",
      "url": "https://physics.aps.org/featured-article-pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.116.061102"
    },
    {
      "title": "First observation of gravitational waves",
      "publishDate": "1997-11-03T10:03:39.123Z",
      "url": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_observation_of_gravitational_waves"
    },
    {
      "title": "Gravitational Waves Detected 100 Years After Einstein's Prediction",
      "publishDate": "1997-11-03T10:03:39.123Z",
      "url": "https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/news/ligo20160211"
    }
  ]
}];


function getArrayByName(name) {
  return data.filter(
    function(item) {
      return item[name];
    }
  )[0][name];
}

var found = getArrayByName('youtube');

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = found[0].url;
```

Here we are first filtering the data array by the name property. So, all elements in the data array which contain the supplied name will be returned. Then we are accessing the first element of the returned list and returning the value of the name property.